# Why are complex functions allowed to have the same derivative in all directions while multivariable functions aren't?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Comsider a multivariable function from $R^2$ to $R^2$ which is $f(x,y)=\langle g(x,y), h(x,y)\rangle$. We're initially at $(x,y)$ and we change the argument by a small vector of magnitude $dr$ in two different directions. In this case, the rate of change of $f(x,y)$ will depend on the direction even if the 'small change' is of the same magnitude.

This is because the rate of change is given by gradient•u. So we're bound to have different rates of change in different directions. It's just not possible to change by the same rate in different directions.

But if we have a complex differentiable function $c(z)$. If we're initially at $z$ and change by $dz$ in two different directions, then the rate of change is the same.

How do complex functions make this work? My math level is high school. Don't use advanced math in the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, so let me just say this: complex differentiability is a much stronger condition than multivariable real differentiability. To say a single variable function (real or complex) is differentiable is to say (more or less) that the function has to look locally like a linear $mx + b$ function. In the complex case, this involves a rotation, scaling (from multiplying by complex $m$), and a translation (adding $b$). So, complex differentiable functions have to preserve angles as well as just be smooth in a multivariate real sense.

Comment: When you are looking at $\mathbb{R}^2$, the “usual” operations act coordinatewise: addition is $(a,b)+(x,y) = (a+x,b+y)$, and the multiplication you can define on the plane in terms of the real multiplication is $(a,b)(c,d) = (ac,bd)$. When you work with the complex numbers, though, the sum works like it does in the reals, but multiplication does not: multiplication by $i$ acts like a rotation, sending the point $a+bi$ to the point $-b+ai$ (so the point with coordinates $(a,b)$ ends up at the point with coordinate $(-b,a)$) (cont)

Comment: (cont) In a sense, that tells you that complex differentiability is a much stronger condition; it has to be well behaved with respect to more types of transformations of the domain than the 2-real-variable case. That’s why whereas in the real numbers (and in the real plane) you can have a function that is $n$-times differentiable but not $n+1$ times differentiable, but over the complex numbers as soon as you have differentiability once, you have arbitrarily-many-times-differentiability: the conditions is just way stronger because the structure is richer.

Comment: All this is because complex differentiability is, er, well, _complex_ (pun intended). Do you realize that a complex function is in fact ***two*** multivariable functions: one for the real part, and another for the imaginary one? When you take each of them by itself, it looks just like any other differentiable multivariable function next door. But they are linked together in an intimate way. Why? Well, because we ***defined*** the complex differentiability like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a single-variable real number line, you actually have two directions.
Given a function $f$ with a positive derivative at $x_0,$ if you increase $x$ very slightly from $x_0$ then you increase $f(x),$
but if you decrease $x$ then you decrease $f(x).$
An increase is a positive change, a decrease is a negative change, and non-zero positive is never equal to negative.

So why do we say there is only one derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ when we can change $f(x)$ in two different ways? It's because the way we measure the *rate* of change makes them the *same rate.*
For example, with the function $f(x) = 2x$ (choosing a linear function so we don't have to worry about the "limit" so much), if the change in $x$ is $+1$ (increasing) then the change in $f(x)$ is $+2,$ whereas if the change in $x$ is $-1$ (decreasing) then the change in $f(x)$ is $-2.$
But the *rate* in each case is
$$ \frac{2}{1} = \frac{-2}{-1} = 2. $$

If we take the complex function $f(z) = 2z,$ if the change in $z$ is $+1$ then the change in $f(z)$ is $+2,$ if the change in $z$ is $+i$ then the change in $f(z)$ is $+2i,$ etc.  No matter how we change $z,$ it turns out $f(z)$ always changes by exactly $2$ times the change in $z.$

For the function $g(z) = 2iz,$ it turns out that no matter which way $z$ changes, $g(z)$ changes by exactly $2i$ times as much.
If we add $1$ to the real part of $z$ without changing the imaginary part, then the real part of $g(z)$ doesn't change at all, but the imaginary part increases by $2.$
If we add $1$ to the imaginary part of $z$ without changing the real part, then the imaginary part of $g(z)$ doesn't change at all, but the real part *decreases* by $2,$
because $2i \cdot i = -2.$

In your example of a function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2,$
you actually set up two independent real-valued functions on $\mathbb R^2,$
each of which has to be independently differentiable in order for $f$ to be differentiable.
But when we have a function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C,$ only the single complex output value $f(z)$ has to be differentiable.
A "change by $dz$" in any "direction" will result in the same *rate of change*
$\frac{df}{dz}$; it's just that if $\frac{df}{dz}\neq 0,$ some "directions" of $dz$ multiplied by $\frac{df}{dz}$ will produce more change to apply to the real part of $f$, and some will produce more change to apply to the imaginary part of $f.$

It turns out that differentiable functions from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ don't generally correspond to differentiable functions from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C,$ because the real and imaginary parts of the output of a differentiable complex function cannot change independently; their changes have to be coordinated in order to have only one rate of change at any given point.
So complex differentiability is a stricter condition, viewed in that way;
but it is a condition that plenty of functions can meet.

Answer (score 0):

> If we're initially at z and change by dz in two different directions, then the rate of change is the same.

This is not the case, any more than it's the case that, for a function $f(x, y)$, the derivative is the same in any direction because $df/dx(x_0, y_0)$ is a fixed number.  You need another, independent derivative, say $df/dy(x_0, y_0)$, and then you can determine the derivative in any direction.

$dz$ is analogous to real differential forms like $dx$ and $dy$.  In fact, it's *more* than an analogy; we have $dz = dx + i dy$.  And just like $dx$ and $dy$ correspond to orthogonal directions in the real plane, $dz$ has a corresponding form $d\overline{z}$.

In the case of complex-differentiable functions, we necessarily have $df/d\overline{z} = 0$, unlike the real-differentiable case where you don't necessarily have to have $df/dy = 0$ in order for $df/dx$ to be defined.  This essentially happens because there are more complex numbers than real numbers to divide by, making it harder for the limit

$$\frac{df}{dz} = \lim_{w \to 0}\frac{f(z + w) - f(z)}{w}$$

to be defined.